# Insert data fetched from API in a table on static website

Tags: javascript, hugo

I have a static website built with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) and a table where I'm displaying data from a local datafile and adding certain values that come from an API to complete this data:

```
<table id="markets-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Asset</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Market Cap</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Industry</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{ $dataAssets := getJSON "https://api/v1/ticker/" }}
      {{ range $.Site.Data.assets }}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ .name }}</td>
              <td>{{ .year }}</td>
              {{ range where $dataAssets "name" .name }}
                <td>${{ lang.NumFmt 0 .market_cap_usd }}</td>
                <td>${{ lang.NumFmt 2 .price_usd }}</td>
              {{ else }}
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
              {{ end }}
              <td>{{ .industry }}</td>
              <td>{{ .type }}</td>
              <td>{{ .description }}</td>
            </tr>
      {{ end }}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I then use [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to make this table sortable, filterable and searchable.

This all works fine but my **data is set at build time and static and I want the values coming from the API to be dynamic/"real-time"**.

I can get the data by making a request using axios or jQuery.ajax() but I'm not sure how to integrate this to my table and keep it clean.

I'm open to switching to a different tool/table plugin if there's something out there that makes more sense in my case.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The sole purpose of Hugo is to generate static content. You can generate content from databases and remote database queries, but it will always be static. Static content is easily indexed by search engines and therefore SEO friendly.

One possible solution, and one that is SEO friendly, is to have your content generated on the server every time the data is updated. However, using this solution is ideal in the case your data does not change often, such as once a day, you don't mind stale content for a short period of time, as you have to contend with another vexing issue which deals with browser caching and setting response headers.

Comment: Indeed, my content is mainly static, that's why I'm interested in knowing if and how it is possible to add dynamic data using javascript to static data already existing in my table. For example, the price and market cap values I want are updated every 5 minutes so rebuilding every few minutes doesn't seem like a reasonable solution and leaving stale price values for more than a few minutes isn't an option either.